# ¿Usar dos hojas de estilos en un html?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

tengo una duda, puedo usar dos hojas de estilos en un mismo html ejemplo, tengo importadas dos hojas de estilos...

style1.css y style2.css en mi html tengo elementos que quiero que usen estilos de una determinada hoja y otros de otra, es posible??? si es asi como lo hago

ejemplo: tengo bootstrap y otro framework que tiene sus hojas de estilos cada uno, no podria mezclaros en un solo .css porque cada uno es de un framework distinto como puedo usar los 2?

Comment: Lo mas seguro es que tu pregunta sea eliminada ya que no indica ningún problema, pero de todos modos te responderé, solo que te toca revisar a fondo los dos frameworks y renombrar las clases para que no te entren en conflicto.

Comment: El navegador tomará las hojas de estilo y aplicará la apariencia como de una sóla hoja se tratase, combinará todas las hojas de estilos.

Comment: Creo que lo que dices no es del todo posible, ya que si las dos hojas de estilo contienen algun nombre de una clase o id que sea identica pues tendras errores con el estilo.

Comment: ¿Lo intentaste antes de hacer esta pregunta? ¿Qué resultado obtuviste de dicha prueba?

Comment: si lo intente, pero me toma efectivamente com comenta el comañero de abajo los estilos de la ultima agregada porque como bien comentan en las 2 tengo alguma comunes como la clase primary de bootstrap, pero me gustaria saber si puedo indicar algo como usa primary de boostrap.css o primary de otro.css

Comment: entonces, tu pregunta era lo que acabas de comentar, y no lo que preguntaste exactamente.. por eso el lio en las respuestas, y por eso nadie esta resolviendo tu problema particular.

Comment: @iGeek Te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta, con la información de tu ultimo comentario y que agregues el codigo de tu HTML

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Puedes usar los que quieras.

Si los dos tienen estilos por el mismo elemento, lo importante es el orden en que están llamando en la página.

El que está llamando de último tiene preferencia.

Pero también tienes que recordar la especificidad que está [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad).

Answer (score 1):

las hojas de estilos se aplican en el orden en el que las pongas

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/misestilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

los estilos de bootstrap se aplicaran pero si yo en mi hoja de estilos llamada misestilos.css cambio cualquier atributo, este es el que se vera reflejado
el orden de aplicacion de estilos es en css lo primero que se aplica en el html son attributos style 
ejemplo  de html

```
 <textarea class="form-control"  style="border-color: #2d2d2d" rows="3">
```

luego los estilos contenidos en las hojas de estilos ordenadas en orden de prioridad primero la que se impondrá sobre todas y así sucesivamente
ahora dentro de la misma hoja de estilos tambien se impondra la mas especifica ejemplo

```
div >p>a
```

se impondra sobre

```
div>a
```

por que la primera linea es mas especifica